# Обнуление state при возвращении на главную страницу со второстепенной в react

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, state

При переходе на другую страничку а в последствии - обратно, проявляется баг с state, ниже приведу скриншот консоли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Прогружаю страницу
2. Прохожу по любой ссылке на странице
3. Возвращаюсь назад и он пытается прогрузить объявления с 17 по 32, хотя с 1 по 16 еще не прогружены

При этом, теперь каждый раз на действие вызова функции он пытается вызвать объявления с 17 по 32 (ot - с какого объявления надо выгружать данные, do - сколько объявлений должно вернуться), пока полностью не перезагрузишь страницу приложения.

*Сообщение ошибки:* 
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

*Код:*

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          ot_ad: 0,
          Ads: []
        }
        this.change_ot_ad = this.change_ot_ad.bind(this)
        this.addAds = this.addAds.bind(this)
      }

      change_ot_ad() {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            ot_ad: prevState.ot_ad + 16
          }
        })
      }

      addAds(allAds) {
        this.setState({Ads: [...this.state.Ads, allAds]})
      }

      render() {                                                       
        // This is add Ads is recomendation

        // Loading ads when a class .bottom-main is visible
        const os = new OnScreen();
        os.on('enter', '.bottom-main', 
              () => {
                if (this.state.Ads[this.state.Ads.length - 1] !== " ") {
                  this.addAds(reqwestAds(this.state.ot_ad)); 
                  this.change_ot_ad();
                  console.log('Ads: ', this.state.Ads)
                }
              }
        )

        // get Ads from the server
        function reqwestAds(ot_ad) {
          console.log('ot: ', ot_ad,', do: ', 16);
          let dataString = '&ot=' + ot_ad + '&do=' + 16;

          let reqwest = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ссылка",
            async: false,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) { return data }
          });

          return allAdsFunc(reqwest.responseJSON)
        }

        function allAdsFunc(AdsData) {
          console.log('Data: ', AdsData);

          if (AdsData.length === 0) {
            return " "
          }

          var allAds = AdsData.map(item => <AdsBlock key={item[0]}
                                                     item={item} />);

          return allAds
        }
```

Пытался обновить `state` добавлением компонента `componentWillMount`, однако это не помогло:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ot_ad: 0})
    console.log('*-------------------------------------------*')
    console.log('ot_ad:', this.state.ot_ad)
  }
```

Како эту проблему можно решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Баг возникал из-за OnScreen. Заменил все теги `Link` на странице на `a`. Тем самым страница стала обновляться при переходах по внутренним ссылкам.